# Reduction of order: $xyy''+2y^2=x(y')^2-2yy'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I've stumbled across this DE and i can't seem to solve it: 
$$
xyy''+2y^2=x(y')^2-2yy';
$$
I've tried $y'=p$ so that $y''=pp'$ and replacing but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
xyy''-x(y')^2=-2yy'-2y^2\qquad |:y^2
$$
(note that $y=0$ is a solution which we have lost)
$$
x\frac{yy''-(y')^2}{y^2}=-2\frac{y'}{y}-2
$$
$$
x\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'=-2\frac{y'}{y}-2
$$
$$
xz'+2z+2=0,\quad z=\frac{y'}{y}.
$$